# How to create one hour time slots between start and end timestamp date?

Tags: java, spring-boot, timestamp

I want to create one hour time slots between two date and save all one hour slots with start and end date. How can do it?

For example

```
start date:08/09/2019 13.00
enddate:08/09/2019 16.00
```

and ı want to get

```
08/09/2019 13.00- 08/09/2019 14.00
08/09/2019 14.00- 08/09/2019 15.00
08/09/2019 15.00- 08/09/2019 16.00
```

Thanks,

Comment: What do you mean with time slots?

Comment: @ConstantinBeer I want to create 1-hour time zones between start and end dates. For example start date:08/09/2019 13.00 enddate:08/09/2019 16.00 and ı want to get 08/09/2019 13.00- 08/09/2019 14.00  ////// 08/09/2019 14.00- 08/09/2019 15.00 ///// 08/09/2019 15.00- 08/09/2019 16.00 thanks

Comment: Post clarifications as edits to your Question rather than as Comments. Don’t expect your readers to crawl through comments to understand your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## *java.time*

The modern solution uses the *java.time* classes.

### `LocalDateTime`

Use `LocalDateTime` to represent a date with time-of-day. Be aware that without a time zone of offset-from-UTC, this type does *not* represent a moment, is *not* a point in the timeline.

```
LocalDateTime start = LocalDateTime.parse( "2019-09-08T13:00:00" ) ;
LocalDateTime stop = LocalDateTime.parse( "2019-09-08T16:00:00" ) ;
```

### Loop, hour by hour

Loop, adding an hour at a time, until past the stopping point.

```
List< LocalDateTime > slots = new ArrayList<>() ;
LocalDateTime ldt = start ;
while (
    ldt.isBefore( stop ) 
) {
    slots.add( ldt ) ;
    // Prepare for the next loop. 
    ldt = ldt.plusHours( 1 ) ;
}
```

### `ZonedDateTime`

If you want to track actual moments, specify a time zone.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Africa/Casablanca" ) ;
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( "2019-09-08T13:00:00" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = ldt.atZone( z ) ;
```

Then follow the same logic we saw in code above. Loop hour-by-hour, collecting `ZonedDateTime` objects.